# Migrate GCP Ubuntu compute instance to Azure using Azure Migrate, pushinstallclient error

Tags: azure, azure-migrate

Am trying to migrate the Ubuntu 16 compute instance from GCP to Azure using Azure Migrate.

According to documentation, we need to install `UBUNTU-16.04-64_pushinstallclient.tar.gz` from their Program Data repository.

When I try to run this install script

```
(venv) test@machine1:/tmp$ mkdir MobSvcInstaller
test@machine1:/tmp$ tar -C /tmp/MobSvcInstaller -xvf UBUNTU-16.04-64_pushinstallclient.tar.gz
pushinstallclient
(venv) test@machine1:/tmp$ cd MobSvcInstaller/
(venv) test@machine1:/tmp/MobSvcInstaller$ ls
pushinstallclient
(venv) test@machine1:/tmp/MobSvcInstaller$ sudo ./install -r MS -q
sudo: ./install: command not found
(venv) test@machine1:/tmp/MobSvcInstaller$ sudo ./pushinstallclient

(C) 2022 Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

/tmp/MobSvcInstaller/pushinstallclient
usage: ./pushinstallclient -c <spec file>
usage: ./pushinstallclient --reboot
```

According to documentation certificates should be formed here?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/tutorial-migrate-gcp-virtual-machines

[image: Azure Documentation]

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong files:

`UBUNTU-16.04-64_pushinstallclient.tar` ❌

Try untaring the following file::

```
Microsoft-ASR_UA_9.48.0.0_UBUNTU-16.04-64_GA_10Apr2022_Release.tar
```

It contains the `install.sh` script, which you can run with the following command:

```
sudo ./install -r MS -q
```

Also, make sure your VM kernel is compatible for the migration, based on [Microsoft's reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-physical-azure-support-matrix#ubuntu-kernel-versions).

[image: Screenshot of files in application vm for installing Mobility service]